# Is Ubuntu Studio suitable for full-stack software development?

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-studio, web-development

I've been using Linux Mint 19.3 for learning full-stack software development and everything works fine (VS Code, Ruby, React, etc.).

Soon I'll begin producing music (I'm starting a home studio) and after some research, I've come to the conclusion that Ubuntu Studio is a good distro for this purpose.
So I'm deciding whether should I make a dual boot or simply migrate to Ubuntu Studio.
I'm not a big fan of multi-boot (I had Windows/Linux for a while and in the end, I prefer to use a virtual machine whenever I need a different OS). Also, I've read in some forums that sometimes a dual boot with Linux alongside Ubuntu can cause some trouble, especially in the UEFI configurations.

If this is true, I would prefer to simply migrate to Ubuntu Studio, but I'm afraid that some things might not work the way I expect. For example, could the low latency kernel affect some of the packages commonly used in software development?

I'd appreciate your advice on this. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to create a dual boot setup, you can have low latency & generic kernels installed, and select which you'll use at boot time (ie. single OS only required to be installed, reboot required to switch kernel).  Low latency has created issues for some applications & environments so the generic kernel is suggested in Ubuntu Studio documentation too (unless low-latency is required).  You didn't give release details so I've stayed generic.

Comment: I see no way how a lowlatency kernel can affect software development.